# объединить два столбца со схожими словами inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть две таблицы: books и newspaper
в них есть столбец `books_name` и `newspaper_title`
Я их объединил следующим образом

```
Select * FROM books b
  inner join newspaper n on b.books_name = n.newspaper_title
```

но я хочу дополнить `inner join`, чтобы находил схожие слова.

Например
`b.name` Гарри Поттер и узник Азкабана и `n.title` Принц Гарри отказался от титула

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Вы хотите объединять не по полному значению, а по наличию общей подстроки? Тогда пишите функцию, которая парсит два значения на слова и возвращает TRUE, если списки слов пересекаются.

Comment: @Akina нафиг функцию. в триггере при вставке разбивать на слова и сливать в отдельную таблицу. но потом встанет вопрос морфологии.

Comment: @teran Согласен, что изменение схемы хранения и нормализация - это правильный подход. Мой коммент - как это выполнить на текущей структуре.

Comment: хотя мб сюда FTS по обоим столбцам прикрутить

Comment: @akina не могли ли бы вы на примере показать, так как я не понял вашего ответа

Answer (score 3):

> не могли ли бы вы на примере показать

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, txt VARCHAR(255));
> CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT, txt VARCHAR(255));
> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 'word1 word2 word3'), (2, 'word4 word5');
> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (123, 'word6 word5 word2'), (456, 'word3 word1');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> WITH 
> cte1 AS ( SELECT t1.id, t11.value
>           FROM t1
>           CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (t1.txt, ' ') t11 ),
> cte2 AS ( SELECT t2.id, t21.value
>           FROM t2
>           CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (t2.txt, ' ') t21 )
> SELECT t1.txt t1_txt, t2.txt t2_txt, STRING_AGG(cte1.value, ',') common_words
> FROM cte1
> JOIN cte2 ON cte1.value = cte2.value
> JOIN t1 ON t1.id = cte1.id
> JOIN t2 ON t2.id = cte2.id
> GROUP BY t1.txt, t2.txt;
> ```
>
> | t1_txt | t2_txt | common_words |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | word1 word2 word3 | word3 word1 | word1,word3 |
> | word1 word2 word3 | word6 word5 word2 | word2 |
> | word4 word5 | word6 word5 word2 | word5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=101cfe460d434ba6414183a5dedff07e)*